# Limit properties on instantiation of Typescript object

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I know per this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/31/announcing-typescript-2-9/#json-imports) that well typed JSON can easily be assigned to an object. For example with the class:

```
export class User {
    id?: number;
    username: string;

    constructor(username: string) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

If I had a JSON formatted variable `jsonUser`:

```
const jsonUser = {
    username: bob,
};
```

Then I could easily say:

```
user: User = <User>jsonUser;
```

The question I have is how do I write a class, if possible, which limits the properties that class can have. For example:

```
const jsonUser = {
    username: bob,
    email: bob@bob.bob
};
```

My `User` class as defined above does not have email in it. Currently, it allows `email` to be assigned as a property to my variable of type `User`. I'd rather it throw an error or not assign it.

Comment: More importantly, why do you expect this typecast to cause issues when it does compile? Do you plan on using functions like `Object.values()` or `Object.keys()` on an object that has only one or two properties on it?

Comment: I don't and it doesn't. I want it too. I want to define a class where the only properties allowed on it are the ones I defined. It's a model for a user, and I'd rather not allow someone to add user.isANiceCar to it. If it can't be done, no big deal. I'm a big fan of strict type checking and trying to prevent unintended use of a model.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a type assertion to say that an object literal is a class instance, as `user instanceof User` will return `false` at runtime.  Type assertions have no runtime effect; they are not "casting" as you might think.  Instead, I'd have a `User` constructor or static method which produces a `User` from a `User`-like object, which only copies the properties you care about.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I just tested it. I'm really surprised to see that jcalz. Thanks. it does make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought this wouldn't be possible, but I found [this interesting post](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-420391352) in a feature request for exact types in TypeScript.

Essentially you can do this:

```
export class User {
    id?: number;
    username: string;

    constructor(username: string) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}

type Exact<A extends object> = A & {key: keyof A};

const jsonUser = {
    username: 'bob',
};

const jsonUser2 = {
    username: 'bob',
    id: 2
};

const jsonUser3 = {
    username: 'bob',
    email: 'bob@bob.bob'
};

const user: User = jsonUser as Exact<User>; // OK
const user2: User = jsonUser2 as Exact<User>; // OK
const user3: User = jsonUser3 as Exact<User>; // TypeScript error
```

The final assignment gives me the following TypeScript error:

```
Conversion of type '{ username: string; email: string; }' to type 'Exact<User>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type '{ username: string; email: string; }' is not comparable to type '{ key: "id" | "username"; }'.
    Property 'key' is missing in type '{ username: string; email: string; }'.
```

Not the most intuitive message but it does the job.

Credit for the solution goes to [Rafał Łużyński (mindbrave)](https://github.com/mindbrave) on GitHub.

Comment: Interesting. Not quite what I was looking for but I think your post gives the answer. It can't be done nicely.